# c# RegEx, how to filter the resultset of regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string “banaanapplebanaanappleapplebanaanappleappbanaanaapple”, 
1.  If I want to extract “apple”, the below resultset applys well.
RegEx : apple
result : "banaanapplebanaanappleapplebanaanappleappbanaanaapple”
[image]

2. If I want to extract “banaana” the below query works well.
   RegEx : banaana
   result :
   “banaanapplebanaanappleapplebanaanappleappbanaanaapple”
   [image]
3. I want to match “apple and banaana” 
   RegEx : banaana
   result :
   “banaanapplebanaanappleapplebanaanappleappbanaanaapple”
   [image]
   I want my resultset to contain only two matches of the apple..
   How can I achieve this with regex?

Comment: Your result does only contain two matches of apple... So I don't see the problem?

Comment: I don't want any "banaana" to be listed in my resultset..

Comment: ah I see, maybe just add that for clarification.

Comment: I want only "apple" to be listed and "banaana" to be filtered out..

Comment: But you did that in your first example?

Comment: Yeahh.. its just an example.. the real problem is listed at 3.

Answer (score 1):

You actually need an alternation operator with capturing group.

```
banaana|(apple)
```

The idea is, first `banaana` would greedily match all the banaana strings. `|` OR `(apple)` capture `apple` strings only from the remaining characters. So this won't overlap with banaana strings.

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/IF9YA4/1)

Comment: I actually have a stream of data, in which many overlappings are also present.. I just want a regex which matches the pattern but the output should contain only 1 kind..

Comment: I thought you don't want the overlapped match.. what's wrong with using the above regex? just consider only the chars inside the capturing group.. And also you can get the group(1) count.. Some languages support `\K` https://regex101.com/r/IF9YA4/2

Comment: You are right I don't want the overlapped match.. from the resultset I want all banaana to be excluded